# Time Calculation

Tags: jquery

I am on a time calculation to calculate a delay time for a train
Schedule time : t1
Arrival time : t2

```
function tomdiff(t1,t2) {
    var t1 = hour2mins(t1);  var t2=hour2mins(t2);
    var ret = mins2hour(parseInt(t2-t1));
    if(t2<t1) {ret=mins2hour(parseInt(parseInt(t2+1440)-t1));}
    return ret;
}

//Calculate on Key up
    $("input.[rel=time1]").keyup(function (b){ $("#delaytime").val(tomdiff($("#schedule").val(),$("#arrival").val())); });
```

This is working great but what if the train arrive earlier!

Can someone advise me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you're trying to handle wrapping across midnight (the magic number `1440` minutes is 24 hours) with insufficient information.

If `t1` and `t2` are `Date` instances, the code doesn't have to do all that mucking about with hours and minutes, and doesn't have to worry about midnight:

```
function tomdiff(t1, t2) {
    var msdiff;

    msdiff = t2 - t1; // When you perform arithmetic on dates, their
                      // underlying EpochMS value (milliseconds since
                      // Jan 1, 1970) is used
    return msdiff / 1000 / 60; // Milliseconds => minutes
}
```

If `t1` and `t2` are not `Date` instances, they should be. :-) Presumably you have the date as well as time of the train's scheduled and actual arrival times. The `Date` constructor lets you feed those in:

```
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond ])
```

If you find yourself needing to do a lot with date/time calculations (and parsing and displaying), I'd look at [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/).

Comment: well i have a date field (#jLdate) that is link to the date of arrival!

Comment: @user: If you have the date and time in some format (even if it's textual), you should be able to convert that into a `Date` instance you can do date/time arithmetic with. (Again, perhaps with the help of DateJD.)

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding the question correctly, but if you are calculating the train delay and it is not delayed then the delay is 0.

No?

Edit:

Using Date.js as I mentioned below, you can do funky stuff like..

```
 Date.parse('now - 10 hours');
 Date.parse('15-04-2011').add(-1).day()
```

If you do use DateJs just be aware of culture/localization

```
<!-- Set the CultureInfo to de-DE (German/Deutsch) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="date-de-DE.js"></script>
```

Comment: Then that is an issue with how you are calculating the difference. You have not listed the functions you are using but I assume you are not taking date into account?

Comment: You may want to look at something tried and tested like http://www.datejs.com/ for doing the calculation

Answer (score 0):

looks like you gotta need to add a date field there. So, you will check the date of the t1 and t2 first before calculating the date. Or probably converting them to unix timestamp and do calculation on that (after adding the date of course).